# PostgreSQL select query to extract coordinates from a point

Tags: sql, split, postgresql-9.1

I have below table with coordinate values in postgres text data type column

```
create table xy(coordinates text)

insert into xy values('1234567.67890,45678.901234;7890123.67890,67890.801234;5678902.67834,90123.101234')
insert into xy values('3214567.234721,12456.890123')
insert into xy values('4532890.783421,453212.23412')
```

Each row contains any no of coordindates.i want to split by using semicolon.

i want below output.

```
x
-
1234567.67890,45678.901234
7890123.67890,67890.801234
5678902.67834,90123.101234
3214567.234721,12456.890123
4532890.783421,453212.23412
```

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_to_array()` and `unnest()` for that:

```
select t.x
from xy, unnest(string_to_array(xy.coordinates, ';')) as t(x);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/COI94042

Edit: I *think* with the ancient 9.1 version the following should work:

```
select unnest(string_to_array(xy.coordinates, ';')) as x
from xy;
```

Comment: ERROR:  function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
LINE 2: from xy, unnest(string_to_array(xy.coordinates, ';')) as t(x...

Comment: @Ram: this is caused by your unsupported and outdated Postgres version. See my edit

Comment: ok.my version supporting split_part function,is there any way to achieve my logic using split_part function or any other function

Comment: @Ram: 9.1 supports [string_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) as well